# Trigger a modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have problem with trigger a modal, 
i check for jquery and its ok.

I am using 1.12.4 version and i have tag in head of code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

My open modal tag is:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" class="modal-trigger" data-id="11" href="#komentarM"></a>
```

And my modal cocde is:

```
<div id="komentarM" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <h4>Modal Header</h4>
        <p>A bunch of text</p>
    </div>
    <input type="text" name="id" value=""></input>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#!" class=" modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Agree</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

With this code i try trigger showing a modal:

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#komentarM').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    alert('da');
    });
});
</script>
```

Just for note, modal was show but trigger not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the code you've provided, I created this in a `.html` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa"
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <a data-toggle="modal" class="modal-trigger" data-id="11"
     href="#komentarM">Howdy</a>
</body>

<div id="komentarM" onload="funtiontest()" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <h4>Modal Header</h4>
    <p>A bunch of text</p>
  </div>
  <input type="text" name="id" value=""></input>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="#!" class=" modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Agree</a>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#komentarM').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    alert('da');
    });
});
</script>
```

Note that I added `Howdy` inside the `<a>` tags meant to trigger the modal. That makes it so there is an area where the user can click. I clicked on the link, the alert appeared, followed by the modal. This works on Safari 10.0.3. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Thanks dude :D i am add 
  `<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>` and its works now!

Answer (score 0):

**I don't think there is wrong in your html code. As you can see below its properly working in Chrome/Firefox. I hope this might work for you**

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.1/css/materialize.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

  <a data-toggle="modal" class="modal-trigger" data-id="11" href="#komentarM">Modal Open</a>

  <div id="komentarM" class="modal">
      <div class="modal-content">
          <h4>Modal Header</h4>
          <p>A bunch of text</p>
      </div>
      <input type="text" name="id" value=""></input>
      <div class="modal-footer">
          <a href="#!" class=" modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Agree</a>
      </div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#komentarM').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        alert('da');
      });
    });
  </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**First:** Input tags don't need to be closed, so I advise you to remove the close tag for `input` and leave it like this:

```
<input type="text" name="id" value="">
```

**Second:** The `data-toggle` and `href` attributes already link the anchor to open the modal, so you don't need the javascript function to do it, simply use your html code

[See it working here](http://www.bootply.com/pQC6aT8Jc9)